# New Entity's navigation property is also inserted when entity is saved

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My object's navigation property is also being inserted when the new object is saved.

```
var car = contextInstance1.GetCar(23);
var passenger = new Passenger{ Car = car, CarId = 23 };
...
contextInstance2.Passengers.Add(passenger);
contextInstance2.Save();
```

In this case, EF tries to insert the Car, which throws an exception. If I clear the property before saving, it works as expected.

Is this the expected behavior (due to different context or something else)? Is there a way to indicate not to try and insert the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because for Context #2, the instance of Car is not tracked. When setting navigation properties you should always ensure that the entities are loaded by the same DbContext instance. If that is not possible, then:

Check that the entity isn't already tracked by the 2nd DbContext. If not, Attach it, if it is, replace the reference:

```
var passenger = new Passenger{ Car = car, CarId = 23 };
...
var trackedCar = contextInstance2.Cars.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CarId == car.CarId);
if (trackedCar != null)
    passenger.Car = trackedCar;
else
    contextInstance2.Attach(passenger.Car);

contextInstance2.Passengers.Add(passenger);
contextInstance2.Save();
```

Testing the `.Local` in the DbSet does not go to the database, just the local tracking cache for the context. If we find a match then we need to update the reference to use that instance. Otherwise we can attach the untracked instance which tells EF to expect that Car #23 points to an existing record rather than treated as a new Car.